# unity3D: sprite animation bug?

Tags: unity-game-engine

need a little help here. Just today I notice that everytime I create a sprite animation, unity3D don't ask for animation filename anymore. It just automatically create animation file on the same directory of the sprites.

Is this configurable in setting or bug?

[demo of the problem](https://youtu.be/-XUsNaihZm0)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried resetting the window layout to factory and checking if there's anything unusual in the inspector window?

Something similar happened to me a while ago and that fixed it. Although it wasn't the same issue, it might be worth a try.